# How can I mount Raspberry with Mac

Tags: macos, raspberry-pi, sshfs

I got my new raspberry pi, finished the setup, gave it static ip, and was able to ssh it from my Mac using:

```
ssh pi@192.168.1.43
```

Then I installed both Fuse and SSHFS from [here](https://osxfuse.github.io/), then read [this](http://bhfsteve.blogspot.com/2012/06/using-sshfs-from-osx.html) and [this](https://amaral.northwestern.edu/resources/guides/mounting-remote-folder-os-x-over-ssh) and [this](https://blogs.harvard.edu/acts/2013/11/08/the-newbie-how-to-set-up-sshfs-on-mac-os-x/) and did the below in my Mac:

```
Last login: Sat Nov 24 10:46:22 on ttys003
Hasans-Air:~ h_ajsf$ mkdir ~/ssh_pi
Hasans-Air:~ h_ajsf$ sshfs pi@192.168.1.43:/home/pi ~/ssh_pi
pi@192.168.1.43's password: 
Hasans-Air:~ h_ajsf$
```

But did not get the SSHFS drive appearing in my desktop or any where else, I'm at macOS Mojave.

Knowing that I was able to mount it with my Windows 10, as explained [here](https://codeyarns.com/2018/05/03/how-to-mount-remote-directory-on-windows-using-sshfs-win/) by installing [WinFSP](https://github.com/billziss-gh/winfsp/releases/tag/v1.3) and [SSHFS-Win](https://github.com/billziss-gh/sshfs-win/releases/tag/v2.7.17334) then mapping the drive using path:

```
\\sshfs\pi@192.168.1.43
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly happened, but after I restarted my mac, I tried the same command, and gt different message that the mount point already exists:

```
Hasans-Air:~ h_ajsf$ sshfs pi@192.168.1.43:/home/pi ~/ssh_pi
mount_osxfuse: mount point /Users/h_ajsf/ssh_pi is itself on a OSXFUSE volume
Hasans-Air:~ h_ajsf$
```

Then I found it there in the founder.

I ejected it, then mounted it again, and it was done without a need of a restart.

[image]